# How to output a given set of strings using JavaScript while loops

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I need a way to output the following using while loops. As I understand it, I will need to use nested loops, but being a beginner, I'm not sure how to go about it. The object is to introduce numbers 1 to n=5:

"welcome 1"

"welcome 2, meet 1"

"welcome 3, meet 1 and 2"

"welcome 4, meet 1, 2 and 3"

"welcome 5, meet 1, 2, 3 and 4"

Comment: This might be a handy article: http://www.kirupa.com/html5/loops_in_javascript.htm
Also, http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp

Comment: This is what I have so far obviously it's not counting in the way I want it to, and isn't quite complete. var i = 1, j, n = 5

while ( i < n ) {
  j = 0
  while ( j < n ) {
    console.log("welcome " + i + (j<1 ? '' : ', meet ' + j) + (j<2 ? '' : ', and ' + (j-1))) 
    j++
    i++
  }
}

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting. I'm busy and new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop and an array that accumulates the numbers that have been met. Here's a live example:

```js
var meet = [];
for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  var greeting = "Welcome " + i;
  if(meet.length) {
    greeting += ", meet ";
    if(meet.length > 1) {
      greeting += meet.slice(0, -1).join(", ") + " and ";
    }
    greeting += meet[meet.length - 1];
  }
  alert(greeting);
  meet.push(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on getting it to work the for loop. I'm still trying to figure out how to do this just using a while loop.

Comment: @quidproquo For loops and while loops can be converted back and forth trivially; i.e. `for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { /*code*/ }` is equivalent to `var i = 1; while(i <= 5) { /*code*/ i++; }`